# Google Plus authorization with Symfony2

Tags: oauth, symfony, google-plus

We have bundles for Facebook & Twitter authorization for a Symfony2 app. But what about other sites like Google Plus? There isn't any bundle yet, and I would like to know if someone knows about the right direction to how to implement it.

I think Google Plus uses OAuth. Could it be then implemented with a OAuth bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [KnpOAuthBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpOAuthBundle) (under development) - only the github OAuth provider is implemented though.

You could implemented your own Google OAuth 2.0 Provider ([check this](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/05_custom_oauth_providers.md)) or ask out on IRC, maybe somebody already implemented it.

Answer (score 8):

KnpOAuthBundle is deprecated and recommends using [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle).

HWIOAuthBundle supports several OAuth providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo, etc. So you can keep all your authentication logic in 1 bundle. Usage is very easy: configure google resource owner:

```
hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        google:
            type: google
            client_id: *client_id*
            client_secret: *client_secret
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    firewall_name: *main firewal name*
```

And add routings:

```
google_login:
    pattern: /login/google
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect
```

To start authentication process simply redirect user to `/connect/*provider_name*`, e.g. `/connect/google`